# How do i make lights flicker AFTER turning it on?

Tags: shaders

Im making a scene in which i want these neon lights to flicker after they've been turned on. Before they are on, i want them to be transparent. I've tried attaching a Principled BSDF (with an emission) and a transparent BSDF to a mix shader and keyframe the factor. [image]

However, when i apply the noise modifier, the noise is applied to the whole graph.
[image]

How do I make the noise come into effect only after the factor has changed from 1 to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the modifier panel you should see a check box labeled *Restrict Frame Range*.

Enabling it will open up a panel with options for setting the range of frames the moderator applies to:

[image: Noise modifier showing restrict frame range enabled.]

Comment: thank you! wow didnt realise it was directly in front of me